# Отступ у ребенка body

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с проблемой , почему body не берет в высоту, отступ у первого своего ребенка
Пример кода:

```css
.parent {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  height: 100%;
}

.test {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: blue;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

В инструменте разработчика высота body захватывает настоящую высоту parent, без отступа сверху. Почему и как это исправить?

Comment: `position:absolute` у body решит проблему или `display:inline-block`

Comment: @Grundy так , а в чем проблема ? parent захватывает всю высоту test и ему не нужен инлайн блок или абсолют